# How can I create a task for heroku using node?

Tags: node.js, ruby, heroku

Im trying to write a task for heroku advance schedule.
How can I write a task like this in ruby, in nodejs?

```
desc "Pings PING_URL to keep a dyno alive"
task :dyno_ping do
  require "net/http"
  if ENV['PING_URL']
    uri = URI(ENV['PING_URL'])
    Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

If you prefer to write the task in Node.js, you can create a JavaScript file for it. Here's an example of how you can achieve the same task using Node.js:

```
const https = require('https');

function dynoPing() {
  const pingUrl = process.env.PING_URL;

  if (pingUrl) {
    https.get(pingUrl, (response) => {
      // Do something with the response if needed
    }).on('error', (error) => {
      console.error(`Error pinging URL: ${error.message}`);
    });
  }
}

dynoPing();
```

Comment: thanks. I am getting these errors with the code:  throw new ERR_INVALID_PROTOCOL(protocol, expectedProtocol); and TypeError [ERR_INVALID_PROTOCOL]: Protocol "http:" not supported. Expected "https:"

Comment: Are you aware of our [policy forbidding AI-generated answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/354577)?